# laravel 5.5 storage my file in Bucket aws S3 via proxy

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy

I use Laravel  5.5 set up in  docker environment . All of its outgoing traffic needs to go through a proxy, but I don't know where to set this in Laravel configuration. I need to send file end export vers  s3 bucket via proxy  but I wanted to know if there is some global configuration where you can specify an outgoing proxy. Does such a setting exist?

Comment: can you helep me !!!

Answer (score 1):

in your config/filesystems.php - add 'http' => [...

```
  's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'http'    => [
                 'proxy' => 'http://' . env('AWS_WEBPROXY_HOST') . ':' . env('AWS_WEBPROXY_PORT')
             ],
        ],
```

and don't forget to add your

```
AWS_WEBPROXY_HOST=... 
AWS_WEBPROXY_PORT=...
```

into the .env file